# AWS: Lambda + S3 setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to configure a setup for an already existing lambda function setup and used with an S3 buckets in/out, kind of like the sample AWS pages provide here:

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html
```

The Lambda function that I'm working with does the following:

```
- notices new image in S3 location mybucket-test/images/in 
- creates a .json file at the same S3 location - mybucket-test/images/in
- creates variations of the image at S3 location mybucket-test/images/out
```

My task is about creating a second set of S3 in/out to work with the same lambda function. The AWS tutorial provided at the above link, doesn't mention how to set up the "resize" bucket.
After following the tutorials I ended up with this situation for the Lambda function:

```
- lambda notices new image in S3 location wire-qa/images/in
- creates .json file at the expected location wire-qa/images/in
- creates variations of the image in S3 location mybucket-test/images/out INSTEAD OF placing them into wire-qa/images/out
```

It seems to me there is something simple that I'm missing, but figuring out what it is on my own is already taking a lot of time. 
I looked into all sorts of places to configure the Lambda function to use my bucket wire-qa/images/out,  as well as mybucket-test/images/out. But I have not found so far anything relevant.
Would very much appreciate some help here. I would at least like to understand where in AWS example the bucket S3 "resize" is set up to work with Lambda.

Comment: Just go into the event configuration of your 2nd S3 bucket and add an event to push notifications to your Lambda function.

Comment: @MarkB: I did - that's how Lambda writes the .json file. it is the second S3 location that's not being used. The bucket is the same, but has 2 folders "in" and "out".

Comment: I don't understand why the second location "isn't being used". You should setup events in one bucket, and then setup events in the other bucket, both pointing to the same Lambda function. Then in your Lambda function under the events section it should show 2 event sources.

Comment: Prefix and suffix filters? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-s3-adds-prefix-and-suffix-filters-for-lambda-function-triggering/

Comment: I was able to get it working - I found a separate config file for Lambda file that had to be reset, not AWS file. Thank you every one.